# DDD - How to manage shared entity between aggregates?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

I currently working on DDD architecture on my PHP project.

But i got a problem with aggregate, I have a entity User who have a 'default currency'.
So i create a entity Currency and link my User to one currency.

But i have another domain 'Transaction' who will have a currency linked too and i don't want to create again a entity Currency in Transaction domain.

So my question is : In this case, where to place the currency entity ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most important concepts of Domain-driven design is the ***ubiquitous language*** which represents the business language that is valid and accepted within the same sub-domain. There can be the same names for business entities which are used by business people in different sub-domains although they represent different things in these sub-domains.

For instance, in the domain of a medical center there can be a *Patient* entity in both the *Appointment Scheduling* and *Billing* bounded context. But when employees working on appointment scheduling are referring to the *Patient* they have another model of in mind than people working in the billing department. The patient entity is referred by the same but has different characteristics in these different sub-domains. For instance, the patient in the billing domain requires credit card information which is not required in the appointment scheduling domain.

So first of all you should make sure if your ***Currency*** model is really meaning the same in both of your sub-domains. If it is a prevailing concept that is so crucial and is meaning the same in all your sub-domains (let's say it is part of the core domain of your business) than you can define such entities in a so called ***[Shared Kernel](https://herbertograca.com/2018/07/07/more-than-concentric-layers/)*** introduced by *Eric Evans*. It represents some shared core code base containing core parts of the overall domain model that overlap between bounded contexts and is allows to reuse crucial parts of the domain model which really need to be consistent across bounded contexts.

But be aware of the ***integration and coordination efforts*** as well as the added code dependencies between your sub-domains of using such a shared code-base especially if you are working with different teams and/or a distributed architecture (e.g. using Microservices). So depending on your use case some *duplication* of *Currency* in you different sub-domains could be okay as well to allow your bounded context code to be more autonomous.

Comment: Thanks, finaly i created a Shared part :)

Comment: +1 to the answer. Additionally, like @VoiceOfUnreason points out, it looks like `Currency` is better off as a Value Object in your case. If the data of the currency (Name, Symbol, etc.) serves as its identity, then it is a Value Object. This distinction is not just pedantic; your persistence mechanism will need to work differently depending on whether you have an Entity or a Value Object.

Answer (score 2):

> In this case, where to place the currency entity ?

In this case, you probably don't want an entity at all.

Entities make sense when you have domain logic that is going to change that entity in some way.  I wouldn't guess that either the User or the Transaction would change the *currency*.

It is more common that what you have is an identifier that is used to indicate the relationship between the user and some currency, or between the transaction and some currency.  That reference can have a lot of different forms, but likely what you will have in each case is a *currency code* to represent the currency concept within the context of a user or a transaction.

That representation of the currency code within the user aggregate, or within the transaction aggregate, is likely to express the *value object* pattern, rather than the *entity* pattern.